# CONSUMIR API CON JS

Tags: javascript, html

Hola tengo este código donde intento consumir una API, para rellenar información un formulario de compra, pero no me funciona esta API de comunas y Regiones de Chile.
De verdad no consigo el defecto,
Mi problema mayormente es que no me carga la API, no se ven la regiones al seleccionar el país

```
                   <label for="country">País</label>
                          <select class="form-select d-block w-100" id="country" name="country" required>
                            <option value="chile">Chile</option>
                            <option value="argentina">Argentina</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                          <label for="region">Región</label>
                          <select class="form-select d-block w-100" id="region" name="region" required>
                            <option value="">Selecciona una región...</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                          <label for="comuna">Comuna</label>
                          <select class="form-select d-block w-100" id="comuna" name="comuna" required>
                            <option value="">Selecciona una comuna...</option>
                          </select>
       
                        </div>
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  $('#country').change(function() {

    if ($(this).val() === 'chile') {
      $.getJSON('https://apis.digital.gob.cl/dpa/regiones', function(data) {
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          options += '<option value="' + data[i].codigo + '">' + data[i].nombre + '</option>';
        }
        $('#region').html('<option value="">Selecciona una región...</option>' + options);
      });
    } else {
      $('#region').html('<option value="">Selecciona una región...</option>');
      $('#comuna').html('<option value="">Selecciona una comuna...</option>');
    }
  });

  $('#region').change(function() {
    var regionId = $(this).val();
    if (regionId) {
      $.getJSON('https://apis.digital.gob.cl/dpa/regiones/' + regionId + '/comunas', function(data) {
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          options += '<option value="' + data[i].codigo + '">' + data[i].nombre + '</option>';
        }
        $('#comuna').html('<option value="">Selecciona una comuna...</option>' + options);
      });
    } else {
      $('#comuna').html('<option value="">Selecciona una comuna...</option>');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Algún mensaje de error en consola o error de red?

Comment: Tu problema es que el servidor tiene bloqueo de CORS. El sitio de la API fue creado el 2013 y se ve que está abandonado, hace unos 5 años el ministerio del interior instruyó colocar el bloqueo por CORS a todos los organismos públicos, y como no podía ser de otra manera esta API quedó inútil para ser consumida directamente desde el navegador. La solución más simple es que te bajes los datos y los consumas directamente en tu servidor